# How to import types in intenal typescript type definition file?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

**Scenario**: I wanna use local type definitions for my javascript.

Say I have this javascript file:

```
/// <reference path='type.d.ts'/>
class MyClass {
  /**
   * @param {AClass} a
   * @param {BClass} b
   */
  constructor(a, b) {

  }
}
```

My type.d.ts file:

```
import BaseClass from 'a-node-module'

interface AClass extends BaseClass {
  customProp: number
}

interface BClass extends BaseClass {
  customProp: string
}
```

The problem is: `import BaseClass from 'a-node-module'` breaks the javascript intellisense. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript version 2.2, in `jsconfig.json`, doing the following will make vscode acquire the type from desired files:

```
"typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true,
    "include": [
        "path/to/type.d.ts"
    ]
}
```